# Searching Isekai manga where a man defeats an ant colony and builds a harem as well as a maid cafe

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The mc is reincarnated in another world and goes on an adventure and forms a harem. In the middle chapter he defeats an ant colony and takes in the ant Princess who was new born in his harem. He also starts a maid cafe and finds another reincarnated girl who was a man in his previous life .

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If people post answers that are incorrect, you can comment as much, and then [edit] your post to add details you've realized don't match.

Answer (score 2):

*[Butsuri-San De Musou Shitetara Motemote Ni Narimashita](https://animanga.fandom.com/wiki/Butsuri-san_de_Musou_shitetara_Motemote_ni_Narimashita)* perhaps? Chapter 6 has him defeating the ant queen. Chapter 10 has him opening a Maid Cafe.

> His harem consists of demi-human girls?! I, who was forced to withdraw from my world, to learn magic with an alchemist. While learning, I come upon a moment that only with my eyes could make any girl fall in love.

[image: Front cover of Butsuri-san de Musou shitetara Motemote ni Narimashita]

I found it by searching for `isekai manga ant colony`, which led me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/bkwmq2/need_help_with_manga_name/) where the work was given as an answer.

Comment: Fair warning, it is an adult comic with pretty full nudity.